# A program to model classical EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, software

As per title, i would like to ask if there exists a program where i can create an arbitrary wire with an arbitrary current and get a visualization of electric and magnetic fields around it.

The emphasis is on *simple*, i am looking for something relatively easy to use to develop the intuition.

edit: my background is in molecular dynamics simulations of biological systems. If we can simulate a protein or a piece of DNA, if we can do hybrid QM/MM simulations of biocatalyzed chemical reactions, is it really so hard to simulate *a coiled piece of wire* ? :)

Answer (score 0):

there are programs like this which are used to predict the behavior of *antennas* of any arbitrary size and shape. Ask about this on the amateur radio stack exchange for more information, but be warned: those programs are not simple, because the general problem is not simple either.